# Boolean Converted To decimal.Decimal object in Boto DynamoDB Requests

Tags: python, boolean, amazon-dynamodb, boto

When I send a put item request to dynamoDB using the boto.dynamodb2.table.Table method with a boolean value in one of the item's attributes and then make a get item request on that same item, the attribute value returns as Decimal('1').

```
>>> Table.put_item(data={
    'id': 'sjx7MQrKNqD7uQ6Xc2UepQkBY7xbJxvcGViP',
    'active': True
    })
>>> response = Table.get_item(id='sjx7MQrKNqD7uQ6Xc2UepQkBY7xbJxvcGViP')
>>> print(response)

{'active': Decimal('1'), 'id': 'sjx7MQrKNqD7uQ6Xc2UepQkBY7xbJxvcGViP'}
```

Although there has been a lot of discussion in the boto Github repo about converting [python float values to decimal.Decimal objects](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/1885) or strings before sending them to dynamoDB to maintain data integrity, I have been unable to find any discussion about booleans being converted.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html) indicates that a boolean is an acceptable datatype and doesn't mention anything about it being converted to a string like numbers are. But, there is a cryptic method for Table called [use_boolean()](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.table.Table.use_boolean) with no documentation. So, I'm confused.

Is this a problem other people are experiencing? If so, is there any explanation for it? If not, any clue why my build would be doing this?

Comment: Not sure if the high-level API supports use of booleans as boolean types.  Be sure to update to the latest version of boto or try using the low level client (e.g. dynamodbConnection.put(table, data={active: {"BOOL": true}, ...})

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will probably end up using the low-level to ensure consistent I/O. Would love to use Boto3, but I don't see any support for localhost endpoints yet and need DynamoDB Local for dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just ran into this very same problem myself and dug into the `use_boolean()` a bit further with commentary below and have a solution.

It seems that support for the `Boolean` type in dynamoDB was only added to boto on the 17th of January 2015 in this pull request:
https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/2667

This patch is relatively new (if you consider new <1 year) so may explain why the `use_boolean()` method isn't too well documented, but the approach seems to be similar to the `use_decimals()` method which is well documented in the plain old `boto.dynamodb` tutorial:
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamodb_tut.html#working-with-decimals

In the pull request you can see there is discussion around the importance of and how to maintain backwards compatibility with those users of boto who have already had their boolean types coerced to int.

The pull request introduced a `NonBooleanDynamizer` that is declared as the default `_dynamizer`; unless you call the `use_boolean()` method on your table object. The most relevant part of the patch is as follows:
https://github.com/kain-jy/boto/commit/886c4bf1877538a6acc28dd5f9bdd1c8f1c30dd9#diff-454bd7ad5c48dd01834d852f01e4b573R114

The following should illustrate how to use `boto.dynamodb2` more clearly (I have not fully investigated what the equivalent would be for plain old `boto.dynamodb` but the sprinkling of use_boolean function parameters in the codebase suggests there is a way if needs be):

```
>>> from boto.dynamodb2.fields import HashKey
>>> from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table

>>> data = {'true': True, 'false': False, 'one': 1, 'zero': 0}

>>> table = Table.create('q32109154-test1', schema=[HashKey('hkey')])
>>> data['hkey'] = 'test1'
>>> table.put_item(data=data)
>>> result = table.get_item(hkey='test1')
>>> print [(k, v) for k, v in result.items()]

[(u'hkey', u'test1'), (u'zero', Decimal('0')), (u'true', Decimal('1')), (u'false', Decimal('0')), (u'one', Decimal('1'))]

>>> table = Table.create('q32109154-test2', schema=[HashKey('hkey')])
>>> data['hkey'] = 'test2'
>>> table.use_boolean()
>>> table.put_item(data=data)
>>> result = table.get_item(hkey='test2')
>>> print [(k, v) for k, v in result.items()]

[(u'hkey', u'test2'), (u'zero', Decimal('0')), (u'true', True), (u'false', False), (u'one', Decimal('1'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for unraveling the mystery. In the end, I rebuilt my methods using the boto3 (low-level) client and discovered that every issues I was having with boto.dynamodb2.Table disappeared. The low level client doesn't throw exceptions when you put() to an existing key or delete() a key that doesn't exist. Likewise, it doesn't convert numbers (or booleans) to Decimal classes. Nor fail to reverse engineer the process of decimal conversion on a get() request! So, I came to conclude that all the hidden 'features' of the Table class were ultimately the culprit. Now I see how it was doing it. Thanks.